Получение постов в реальном времени C# WebHook Telegram.Bot
Нужно получать в реальном времени новые посты в телеграм каналах которые указал пользователь в Telegram боте.
public BotController(TelegramBotClient bot, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BotController> logger, AppDbContext context)
{
    _bot = bot;
    _configuration = configuration;
    _logger = logger;
    _context = context;
}

[HttpGet("setWebhook")]
public async Task<string> SetWebhook()
{
    var webappUrl = _configuration["BotWebAppUrl"];
    await _bot.SetWebhookAsync($"{webappUrl}/Bot");
    return $"Webhook set to {webappUrl}/Bot";
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnUpdate([FromBody] Update update)
{
    await OnUpdateAsync(_bot, update, _logger);
    return Ok();
}

Я сделал контроллер который ловит сообщения пользоваетля, но не понимаю как получать новые посты от каналов.

ну, тг-бот сам по себе не может получать сообщение из тг каналов. максимум из групп, если его туда добавить. У телеграма нет публичного апи для таких дел. Можно попробовать разные клиенты которые работают с непубличным апи, но там нужно будет дать боту данные учётки от имени которой он будете сидеть в тг

Вообще, если каналы публичные, то можно просто через веб версию попробовать парсить, через какой-нибудь AngleSharp. Хотя не уверен не подсунет ли телеграм капчу
